# How would you use RxJava to retrieve contacts?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

If I'm retrieving a single contact like so:

```
    private void pickContact() {
        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
        pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
    }



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);

        }
    }
}
```

How would I do it using RxJava? Would RxJava improve this in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do so, use PublishSubject for that.

```
PublishSubject<Contact> contactPipe = PublishSubject.create();
```

When you got another contact, call contactPipe.onNext(newContact);
to access source of contacts use `contactPipe.asObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation);`

Another problem in your code - long operation with db on main thread.
To solve that, use

```
Observable.defer(()-> Observable.just(contactUri))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(t -> {
  Contact c = getContactFromDb(contactUri);
  return c;
}
// you can hand new contact directly, because PublishSubject implement Subscriber
.subscribe(contactPipe);
```

Comment: Hey, I find this confusing. You're passing 'ContactUri' to `Observable.just()`, can you please elaborate what's going on here? Is this after retrieving the data from the intent? Do I have to wait for the callback of onActivityResult to execute this?

Comment: Usually opearators of rx pipeline created once. Observable.defer() operator tell rxJava to create new pipeline every  time this operator is called. It takes your URI (call this in onActivityResult), switches execution onto background thread (.subscribeOn() operator), and then transforms that uri into 'some result'  - you get your actual contact from database (you did that in .onActivityResult), because it is slow operation and should be done not on the main thread.

Comment: After contact is queried from database (.map() operator, it is delivered to PublishSubject (by .subscribe() method)

Comment: Consider using .onErrorReturn() operator if contact can't be queried, because PublishSubject will stop working after error

Comment: When the contact is queried from the database and emiited to PublishSubject, how do I get the contact from there? Do I have to implement onNext before the observable subscribes to PublishSubject?

Comment: PublishSubject will be receiving contacts, but in order to receive it you have to subscribe to it first. You can either use .subscribe(contactPipe), or use .subscribe (contact -> contactPipe.onNext(contact)) - that is the same things. You will want to get single contact, so use contactPipe.asObservable.take(1).subscribe(contact -> handleContact(contact));